# Yii filter search working for one relation but not for other

Tags: activerecord, yii, cgridview

I am using Yii GridView filter and my data comes from Purcahses table.
That tables realted to 
1 .vendors 
2 .clients
Below are my relations in Purchases Model

```
 'vendor' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Vendors', 'Vendor'),
 'client' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Clientsinfo', 'clientID'),
```

and i am using that relations in my admin view , Below is code of admin.php file

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id' => 'purchases-grid',
'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
'filter' => $model,
'columns' => array(
    array(
        'name' => 'Vendor',
        'value' =>'$data->vendor->VendorName',
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'clientID',
         'value' =>'$data->client->Company'
    ),

    array(
        'name' => 'PurchaseType',
        'value' => 'Purchasetype::model()->findByPk($data->PurchaseType)->PurchaseType',
        'filter' => '',
    ),

),
));
```

and lastly here is model search function where is use with and together to get data from other tables

```
public function search() {
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->together = true;
    $criteria->with = array('vendor');
    $criteria->with = array('client');
    $criteria->compare('PurchaseType', $this->PurchaseType);
    $criteria->compare('vendor.VendorName', $this->Vendor, true);
    $criteria->compare('client.Company', $this->clientID, true);
   return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria' => $criteria,
    ));
}
```

Getting data from client successufully , but when i use vendor fitter it throw me error below

## CDbException

CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
 'vendor.VendorName' in 'where clause'. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `t`.`PurchaseID`
) FROM `purchases` `t`  LEFT OUTER JOIN `clientsinfo` `client` ON (`t`.`clientID`=`client`.`ClInfoID`
) WHERE ((Vendor=:ycp0) AND (vendor.VendorName LIKE :ycp1)) (C:\xampp\htdocs\laurenparker\framework
\db\CDbCommand.php:543)

#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\laurenparker\framework\db\CDbCommand.php(433): CDbCommand-

> queryInternal('fetchColumn', 0, Array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youre overriding relations in `criteria`. Change this:

```
$criteria->with = array('vendor');
$criteria->with = array('client');
```

To this:

```
$criteria->with = array('vendor', 'client');
```

Comment: you have only standardize the syntax but its not the solution , i have tried this many time

Comment: It's not standarizing, as i said, youre OVERRIDING `with` property. It won't work if youre still using `vendor` relation after this. In `CDbException` you see, you dont have relation to `vendor` in your query.

Comment: @ Yupik thanks bro i have just reached from and change code according to your suggestion and it start working , Appreciated :)